# Datagridview refresh in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to reset my datagridview , even though the datatable and binding source are changing it is not reflected in Datagridview. I think I am missing something. The idea is to refresh the DGV every second as th enew data comes in. The new data is not just addition of rows but the whole table might change.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = (5000); // 10 secs
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Start();
            MessageBox.Show("You are here");
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView my_datagridview = new DataGridView();
            DataTable my_datatable = new DataTable();
            my_datagridview.DataSource = null;
            BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
            this.Size = new Size(1075, 300);
            my_datagridview.Size = new Size(1075, 400);
            my_datagridview.Location = new Point(5, 5);
            string[] raw_text =
            System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("L:\\cat3_data.csv");
            string[] data_col = null;

            int y = raw_text.Count();

            for (int i = 0; i < raw_text.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    data_col = raw_text[i].Split(',');

                    for (int r = 0; r <= data_col.Count() - 1; r++)
                    {
                        my_datatable.Columns.Add(data_col[r]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    data_col = raw_text[y - i].Split(',');
                    MessageBox.Show(data_col[0]);
                    my_datatable.Rows.Add(data_col);
                }
                source.ResetBindings(false);
                source.DataSource = my_datatable;
                my_datagridview.DataSource = source;
                my_datagridview.Update();
                my_datagridview.Refresh();
                this.Controls.Add(my_datagridview);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You add the gridview each time, this.Controls.Add(my_datagridview); but do you ever remove the old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the gridview each time, this.Controls.Add(my_datagridview); but do you ever remove the old one? My guess is that is why you keep seeing the original one.

You could do either of these options:

```
// if the DataGridView is the only control, you can remove all the controls on the form
// this.Controls.Clear();

// or you can remove all the DataGridView controls if it is the only Datagridview control
this.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>().ToList().ForEach( x => this.Controls.Remove( x ) );

this.Controls.Add(my_datagridview);
```

Comment: I am new at this, so kinda miss the small stuff, Thank you again for helping me out here.

Comment: No problem. If it works for you you can select it as the answer.

Comment: is there any other method to do this? meaning, do we have to clear the DGV everytime some change occur in my database?

Comment: If you are binding to the datatable, you should be able to just do it once, and keep changing the datatable.  But if columns  could be added / removed you probably do need to recreate everything.  Another option, is to not add / remove the whole control, but you could clear all the data and remove all the columns and readd all the columns and data.

Comment: well that sounds like a good way to do it. What I think of doing is to separate the form into two DGV, one with constant terms , which needed to be read only once, while another takes care of changing values. But i ran into this problem of how to clear the form of only one DGV among the two